# 2D dynamic array in C push() possible just 3x

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-reallocation

I have a 2D dynamically allocated array in C and push() function (creaMatri()) which adds a new element of the specified number of subelements to it. Function works for the first three calls like a charm, but for the forth one returns error:

> realloc(): invalid old size

```
void creaMatri(int***arr,int*size,int**dim) {
    int** tmp=realloc(*arr,(*size+1)*sizeof(int));
    if (tmp==NULL) exit(100);
    tmp[*size]=calloc(dim[*size][0]*dim[*size][1],sizeof(int32_t));
    **arr=*tmp;
    (*size)=*size+1;
}

int main() {
    int** matri=malloc(0);
    int matriSIZ=0;

    //code

    creaMatri(&matri,&matriSIZ,sizes);
}
```

**sizes** is 2D array that holds numbers needed for knowing how many subelements the push() needs to allocate.

Comment: Make a 1D array of size *M x N* instead of this ineffective attempt to make a 2D array. `int***` is not being used properly here. Also `malloc(0)` is a really strange thing to see. Allocate with the correct size and *return that from the function*.

Comment: You are allocating space in units the size of an `int`, but using the space as a collection of `int *`.  If your pointers are larger than your `int`s (which is likely) then you therefore invoke undefined behavior by writing past the bounds of the allocated space.  It is plausible that this does not appear to cause a problem until the fourth such action.